# Setting the background color of JFrame isn't working

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe

I've spent a fair bit of time researching how to change the background color of JFrame, but haven't managed to make anything work. My code in its current state looks like this:

final ImageIcon cardIcon = new ImageIcon("cardImages/aceSpades.gif");

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
    {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            cardIcon.paintIcon(this, g, 20, 20);
            }
    };

JFrame window = new JFrame("Deck of Cards");
window.add(panel);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
window.pack();
window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
window.setVisible(true);
```

This is the result of all of the searches I've done on stackoverflow, so some help would be appreciated. I know I need to change the content pane instead of the actual frame, but all of my efforts seem to result in the default grey background. Thanks in advance.

edit: `panel` is for an image that's being loaded in.
edit 2: Sounds like `panel` is blocking the background from changing.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my OP with the definition. Missed that.

Comment: i commented out window.add(panel); and the JFrame background was green, maybe the panel is blocking it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JPanel` you're adding to the frame is blocking the background color. Either set the panel's background color via `panel.setBackground` or make the panel transparent by setting `panel.setOpaque(false)`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Making the panel transparent is included in my answer. >.>

Comment: Sorry, I got to `panel.setBackground` and went, "yep, that's the answer" ;)